# Dynamic switching between RxJava observables

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have two observables: one emits ByteArrays received from Bluetooth connection, another emits the results of periodic server requests.

```
fun observeBluetooth():Observable<ByteArray>
fun observeServer():Observable<ByteArray>
```

Bluetooth connection status is available (as a Boolean variable or as an Observable)

I need to combine the observables taking into account the following requirements:

1. If Bluetooth is connected the data received from observeBluetooth() must be emitted (and server requests must not be made)
2. If Bluetooth is not connected the data received from observeServer()
   must be emitted
3. If Bluetooth connection is restored the data received from observeBluetooth() must be emitted again

How do I do this using RxJava/Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an observable `isBtConnected`, you could switch over it:

```
val isBtConnected: Observable<Boolean> = ...
isBtConnected.switchMap {
    if (it) observeBluetooth()
    else observeServer()
}
```

Comment: You may think that if you don't care about previous data emitted by the bluetooth or server observables. If you do care about that, you should use a `flatMap` instead `switchMap` probably  https://medium.com/appunite-edu-collection/rxjava-flatmap-switchmap-and-concatmap-differences-examples-6d1f3ff88ee0

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro the example is not really comparable. You should not observe BT when it's off. You might not get any data from there anyhow. `switchMap` ensures that it's being disposed of when the server observable starts emitting. There might be better approaches, just `flatMap` is not ideal, since it assumes, that all sources are always active.

Comment: Yes, switchMap() is what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could just filter based on the Bluetooth status. If it is a shared atomic variable:

```java
final AtomicBoolean isConnected = new AtomicBoolean();

Observable.merge(
    observeBluetooth()
       .filter(v -> isConnected.get()),
    observeServer()
       .filter(v -> !isConnected.get())
)
// ... etc.
```

If the status is also observable, it gets a bit more complicated as you need the [`valve`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersvalve) operator from the extensions project:

```java
Observable<Boolean> isConnectedSource = ...

Observable<Boolean> shared = isConnectedSource.publish().refCount(2);

Observable.merge(
    observeBluetooth()
       .compose(ObservableTransformers.valve(shared)),
    observeServer()
       .compose(ObservableTransformers.valve(shared.map(v -> !v), false))
)
// ... etc.
```

Note though that `valve` will pause and keep buffering the items while it is closed. If you need to drop items from the other sequence, you have to combine the two approaches:

```java
Observable<Boolean> isConnectedSource = ...

final AtomicBoolean isConnected = new AtomicBoolean();

Disposable status = isConnectedSource.subscribe(v -> isConnected.set(v));

Observable.merge(
    observeBluetooth()
       .filter(v -> isConnected.get()),
    observeServer()
       .filter(v -> !isConnected.get())
)
// ... etc.

status.dispose();
```